# Formatting POJO inside Grails/GSP select element

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, groovy, grails-controller

I have the following POJO/POGO:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    // ... lots of other fields
}
```

And a Grails 2.3.6 controller:

```
class PeopleController {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>()

    def populatePeople() {
        // Add lots of people to the 'people' list.
    }

    def doSomething() {
        populatePeople()

        render(
            view: "people", 
            model:[
                people: people,
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

And then in the GSP:

```
<div id="peopleSelector">
    <g:select name="people" from="${people}" />
</div>
```

When I run my app I get the `<select>` element with `com.me.myapp.domain.Person@398r4d99`-looking values as `<option>`s. This is obviously Grails not deserializing my `Person` instances into pretty print form.

I want peoples' first and last names to appear as the select options. Hence, if one of the `Person` instances in the `people` list is:

```
Person smeeb = new Person(firstName: "Smeeb", lastNname: "McGuillocuty")
```

Then I would expect "*Smeeb McGuillocuty*" as a select option in the final HTML. **How can I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following method to your `Person` class:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    "$firstName $lastName"
}
```

And, somewhat unrelated to the actual question, you *may* have to add an identifier to your option rows to uniquely identify the person. Assuming the `Person` class has an `id` property:

```
<g:select name="people" from="${people}" optionKey="id" />
```

so that you get the following HTML:

```
<select name="people" id="people">
    <option value="123">Smeeb McGuillocuty</option>
    :
```

Useful link to official doc: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html:
"..The default behaviour is to call `toString()` on each element in the `from` attribute.."

Answer (score 1):

If you can't/won't "sacrifice" `toString()` for rendering in HTML you can also tell the `g:select` how to render the options.  Either by providing the name of a property in `optionValue` (e.g. `optionValue="fullName"` and then provide a `String getFullName()` method (watch out for transients, if you pass a GORM object)) or by providing it directly in the GSP:

```
<g:select name="person" optionKey="theId" optionValue='${{"$it.lastName, $it.firstName"}}' from="${people}" />
```

Comment: That's a weird attitude, but very common - why waste the `toString` format for an html dropdown, when you can do slightly more work to configre the dropdown itself. This isn't something I'm religeous about, but it seems so backwards.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith maybe because you ever had to make heads or tails from some assert or debug-println?  Or it could just be me ;)